# Excel Inserting Images VBA Script

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a spreadsheet where I have the part numbers of various products, the part number is in column Q, I then have a script which is taking the part number and adding it into a script which adds the image to column P.

It works fine for the first 20 lines but then it seems to break down and not add the image or adds it in the row above.

Any ideas what is wrong with the code?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim picname As String
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim pasteAt As Integer
    Dim lThisRow As Long

    lThisRow = 11 'This is the start row

    Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")


        pasteAt = lThisRow
        Cells(pasteAt, 16).Select 'This is where picture will be inserted (column)


        picname = Cells(lThisRow, 17) 'This is the picture name

        present = Dir("z:\1A - MICO IMAGE FILE - OFFICIAL\" & picname & ".jpg")

        If present <> "" Then

            Cells(pasteAt, 16).Select

            Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("z:\1A - MICO IMAGE FILE - OFFICIAL\" & picname & ".jpg", _
            msoCTrue, msoCTrue, Left:=Cells(pasteAt, 16).Left, Top:=Cells(pasteAt, 16).Top, Width:=100, Height:=100).Select


        Else
            Cells(pasteAt, 16) = "Image Unavailable"
        End If

        lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
    Loop

    Range("O1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
  For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Column = 16 Then
            With shp
                .Top = Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Top + ((Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Height - shp.Height) / 2)
                .Left = Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Left + ((Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address).Width - shp.Width) / 2)
            End With
        End If
    Next shp
    Exit Sub
    

ErrNoPhoto:
    MsgBox "Some of the images are not available" 'Shows message box if picture not found
    Exit Sub
    Range("O7").Select
End Sub
```

All images to be inserted, first 20 rows are okay but after images are not inserted in the correct place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the image and adjust its position in a loop to avoid cumulative errors leading to misalignment in the `TopLeftCell` position of the image.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim picname As String, present
    Dim shp As ShapeRange
    Dim pasteAt As Integer
    Dim lThisRow As Long
    Dim anchorCell As Range
    Dim sFile As String
    lThisRow = 11 'This is the start row
    Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 2) <> "")
        pasteAt = lThisRow
        Set anchorCell = Cells(pasteAt, 16) 'This is where picture will be inserted (column)
        picname = Cells(lThisRow, 17) 'This is the picture name
        sFile = "z:\1A - MICO IMAGE FILE - OFFICIAL\" & picname & ".jpg"
        present = Dir(sFile)
        With anchorCell
            If present <> "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, Left:=.Left, _
                    Top:=.Top, Width:=100, Height:=100).Select
                Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange
                shp.Top = .Top + (.Height - shp.Height) / 2
                shp.Left = .Left + (.Width - shp.Width) / 2
            Else
                .Value = "Image Unavailable"
            End If
        End With
        lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
    Loop
    Range("O1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrNoPhoto:
    MsgBox "Some of the images are not available" 'Shows message box if picture not found
    Exit Sub
    Range("O7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this and I get an error showing bad file name or number, pointing to  present = Dir(sFile)

Comment: nvm! Me being an idiot! The drive is through vpn connection!!! Works perfectly thank you very much!